# class ClassName < self in class, and self ^ Classname.new

Tags: ruby

In [the source](https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/2dce252fa67e5bd0afed83039d391fa5ab6edd12/stdlib/promise.rb), I saw `class Trace < self` (line 323)
inside classes, and those classes were called like `self ^ Trace.new(*args)` (line 304).

Please explain those mechanics and their use case. Where can one use such constructs in their code, and what for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different things happening here.

`class Trace < self` builds a new `Trace` class that inherits from `Promise`, which is `self` at that point. In another file, you would have seen this as `class Promise::Trace < Promise`, but since `Trace` is defined in the same file, they used this shorthand.

`self ^ Trace.new(*args)` is calling the method `^` on `self` with the new `Trace` as its argument, just like if you were to call `2 ^ 3` for XOR. `^` is defined on line 160.

Answer (score 0):

`class Trace < self` defines a class `Trace` that is subclass of `self`. In your specific context, and since this definition is inside the `Promise` class, `self` refers to `Promise` and thus `Trace` is defined as a subclass of `Promise`.

Line 304 doesn't involve any kind of magic, `^` is defined as a method at line 160.